# Drop down menu in IE Against FF and Chrome

Tags: php, html, css, url-rewriting

I've noticed my dropdown menu works perfectly in chrome, ff and opera but in IE its a mess - **BUT!** it works in my 404 page.

Examples:
http://www.raal.co.il/
and it works in:
http://www.raal.co.il/asd

The weirdest thing is this: I've copied the 404 page's code to a blank page and put it in the home page - and it still doesn't work!! like the address is related some how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default document mode in IE for http://www.raal.co.il/ is Quirks, and for http://www.raal.co.il/asd it is IE9 standards. (Press F12 for developer tools.) If you change it manually to IE9 standards, you will see the menu works allright.

This is doctype related. So I checked the source code, and I found something weird in the doctype. The first character looks wrong. Unfortunately, I cant copy and paste it here somehow, so you'll have to check yourself.

Has something to do with the Hebrew language I guess..

**Edit:**
In the Firebug Net tab, I found this in front of the doctype:

ï»¿ï»¿

Comment: You're right. When you run the non-404 page through the HTML validator, it complains about `Line 1, Column 1: character "" not allowed in prolog`.

Comment: Yeah it was already changed on my localhost server, wasnt uploaded yet - but the problem exists. 
What do you mean by "change it manually to ie9 standards" - what do i need to change exactly ?

Comment: When you press F12 in IE8/9, you can change the document mode. If you do you'll see the menu works. But thats just to proove there's something wrong with the doctype.